# Cutting down repeating code in c# Class

Tags: c#, class, wrapper

This is a wrapper for an API I'm working on, am I doing it sort of right?  I'm not particularly fond of all the repeating code in the constructor, if someone can show me if  I can reduce that it would be very helpful!

```
public class WebWizForumVersion
{
    // Properties of returned data
    public string Software { get; private set; }
    public string Version { get; private set; }
    public string APIVersion { get; private set; }
    public string Copyright { get; private set; }
    public string BoardName { get; private set; }
    public string URL { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Database { get; private set; }
    public string InstallationID { get; private set; }
    public bool NewsPad { get; private set; }
    public string NewsPadURL { get; private set; }

    public WebWizForumVersion(XmlReader Data)
    {
        try
        {
            Data.ReadToFollowing("Software");
            this.Software = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("Version");
            this.Version = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("ApiVersion");
            this.APIVersion = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("Copyright");
            this.Copyright = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("BoardName");
            this.BoardName = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("URL");
            this.URL = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("Email");
            this.Email = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("Database");
            this.Database = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("InstallID");
            this.InstallationID = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
            Data.ReadToFollowing("NewsPad");
            this.NewsPad = bool.Parse(Data.ReadElementContentAsString());
            Data.ReadToFollowing("NewsPadURL");
            this.NewsPadURL = Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var properties = new [] {
    new {Name = "Software", Setter = new Action<string>(value => this.Software = value)},
    new {Name = "Version", Setter = new Action<string>(value => this.Version= value)},
    new {Name = "ApiVersion", Setter = new Action<string>(value => this.ApiVersion = value)},
    // ...
    new {Name = "NewsPad", Setter = new Action<string>(value => this.NewsPad = bool.Parse(value))},
}

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Data.ReadToFollowing(property.Name);
    property.Setter(Data.ReadElementContentAsString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks a lot better!  But what about handling the different data types, I have a bool hidden in the original question.

Comment: @Tom to fix the boolean problem add this, new {Name = "NewsPad", Setter = (value => this.NewsPad= bool.Parse(value))}

Comment: probably also a `Action` ctor should be added updated the code. Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Hmm.  This is shorter, but looks quite a bit more cryptic.  Not sure if I agree here.

Comment: @Spacemoses, agree. It was less cryptic initially. But also it was less compilable :( I made it more compilable, it became more cryptic.

Answer (score 4):

I'd leave the assignment of your local properties alone, and use helper methods to read the values from the XML.

```
public class WebWizForumVersion
{
    public WebWizForumVersion(XmlReader Data)
    {
        this.Software = Data.ReadString("Software");
        this.Version = Data.ReadString("Version");
        this.APIVersion = Data.ReadString("ApiVersion");
        this.NewsPad = Data.ReadBool("NewsPad");
    }
}

public static class XmlReaderHelpers
{
    private string ReadString(this XmlReader Data, string name)
    {
        Data.ReadToFollowing(name);
        return Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }

    private bool ReadBool(this XmlReader Data, string name)
    {
        return bool.Parse(Data.ReadString(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this version b/c there's no dictionary to maintain

Comment: I like this method because it allows you to easily change the underlying logic if, say, you changed to a database instead of an xml file.  BUT, I would get rid of the boolean version and just cast the special case in the constructor.

Comment: No no...now you went and complicated it.

Comment: I switched ReadString and ReadBool to extension methods because it's better design to not have a field that's only used in the constructor. Though I suppose pulling the methods back into the main class and passing the XmlReader explicitly would do the trick too.

Comment: I see your point good sir.  Here is one thing that no one has mentioned yet though.  Why are we passing in an XmlReader object in the first place?  Wouldn't it be cleaner and less coupled to accept the individual primitives as parameters?

Comment: Less coupled yes, but I think that would probably introduce unneeded complexity. I'm thinking it would end up something like this: `XMLReader xml = ...; string software, version, APIVersion, etc...; XMLSettingsReader.Read(xml, out software, out version, out APIVersion, out etc...); new WebWizForumVersion(software, version, APIVersion etc...);` It may be more coupled, but I think it's better to pass an XMLReader to WebWizForumVersion than to pass 11 individual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Can you have all your values in a Dictionary type of object instead?  So something like this would simplify things:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ForumVars = null;

public WebWizForumVersion(XmlReader Data)
{
    ForumVars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    ForumVars.Add("Software", GetValue("Software"));
    ForumVars.Add("Version", GetValue("Version"));
    ForumVars.Add("APIVersion", GetValue("APIVersion"));
}

protected string GetValue(string key)
{
    Data.ReadToFollowing(key);
    return Data.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

I understand that not everything might be a string (e.g. NewsPad), so you can instead work with dynamic or Object.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah and when using a dictionary a way to simplify it even further is like this.

```
new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"key", "val"},
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you are able to change the name of your `InstallationID` property to `InstallID` to match the element name, then you could use refelction:

```
public class WebWizForumVersion
{
    // Properties of returned data
    public string Software { get; private set; }
    public string Version { get; private set; }
    public string APIVersion { get; private set; }
    public string Copyright { get; private set; }
    public string BoardName { get; private set; }
    public string URL { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Database { get; private set; }
    public string InstallID { get; private set; }  // changed property name
    public bool NewsPad { get; private set; }
    public string NewsPadURL { get; private set; }

    public WebWizForumVersion( XmlReader Data )
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach( PropertyInfo pi in props )
            {
                Data.ReadToFollowing( pi.Name );
                if( pi.PropertyType == typeof( bool ) )
                {
                    pi.SetValue( this, bool.Parse( Data.ReadElementContentAsString() ), null );
                }
                else
                {
                    pi.SetValue( this, Data.ReadElementContentAsString(), null );
                }
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
          // do something with exception
        }
    }
}
```